# Upload a file with another object in same form in Spring

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, file-upload, thymeleaf, multipartform-data

I want to upload a file to database with OneToMany relationship with another entity. I'm using Spring 4 with Thymeleaf.
I have two objects: Image and Store.

Store:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "store")
public class Store {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id; 
    private String email;
    private String nombre;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_image")
    private Image im;

//public getters and setters
```

Image:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "images")
public class Image {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private byte[] image;
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="im",cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Store> stores;
```

Store form:

```
<form th:action="@{/addstore}" th:object="${store}" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <table>

            <tr>
                <td><label>E-mail</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{email}" /></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Nombre</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{nombre}" /></td>

            </tr>

           <!--Here I want to add the option to upload the image -->

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button type="submit">Ok</button>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping("/addstore")
    public String saveStore(@ModelAttribute("store") Store store, 
            @ModelAttribute("file") MultipartFile image){

    //I have to upload the image before insert the store.
    //imageService.insertImage(image);

    storeService.insertStore(store);
}
```

I can to insert a new Store and I can insert a new Image, but I need to insert them in the SAME form.

I use MultipartFile to add a Image to the database (it works) so the MultipartFile configuration is ok. The issue is I don't know how to get the store and image data from the same form.

Please, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is nearly correct, you are just missing a bit of details. First, you need to add an input of type `file` to your form with it's name attribute set to **file**, also add the following tag to your form `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

```
<form th:action="@{/addstore}" th:object="${store}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label>E-mail</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{email}" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label>Nombre</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{nombre}" /></td>
            </tr>
           <input type="file" name="file" accept="image/x-png,image/jpeg,image/jpg"/>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button type="submit">Ok</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</form>
```

Then, change your controller so that it looks like the following version.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addstore", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveStore(@ModelAttribute("store") Store store, 
                        @RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile image){
    imageService.insertImage(image);
    storeService.insertStore(store);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I get the next error: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided]

Comment: Hi Jane! Please, try with the new edited code. This is the other way I have done it.